# How to install libtheora for MacOSX (ffmpeg)

Tags: ffmpeg, ogg-theora

My ffmpeg version is missing 'libtheora' codec and I downloaded this version of 'libtheora' to make it work. http://www.theora.org/downloads/
The problem is that after extracting the zip file, I dont know how to install it. The README file does not give a lot of details. Do I just run make?
Anyone that did this before?

Answer (score 5):

It is very simple with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install ffmpeg2theora
```

But actually it does not allow you to convert to OGG/OGV format after this. What actually helped me to convert MP4 to OGV format in the end was compiling *ffmpeg* with *libtheora* support. Detailed explanation could be found here [ffmpeg Mac OSX compilation guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/MacOSXCompilationGuide). And after this I finally was able to run the [following command](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -codec:v libtheora -qscale:v 7 -codec:a libvorbis -qscale:a 5 output.ogv
```

Comment: Hi there with `ffmpeg2theora ` this command is not correct! This is most simply and correct one:

```shell
ffmpeg2theora <file_input.mp4> --videoquality 7 --audioquality 4 --output <file_output.ogv>
```

Regards

Comment: Hire you have how to add this feature to OSX actions submenu

https://github.com/klich3/OSX-Automator-custom-actions

Answer (score 4):

You can install libtheora for ffmpeg with brew

```
brew install theora
```

To use it in ffmpeg you should recompile ffmpeg. Source of solution: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX

```
brew install automake fdk-aac git lame libass libtool libvorbis libvpx opus sdl shtool texi2html theora wget x264 xvid yasm

git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
./configure  --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
make && sudo make install
```

as for me it works like magic.

Answer (score 2):

after reading a long mailinglist and getting sad because people are rude i finally solved this problem for me. it seems to be necessary to specify the lib paths with `--extra-ldflags` and `--extra-cflags`. so in my case it looked like this:

```
./configure  --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree \
--enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype \
--enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis \
--enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
--extra-ldflags="-L/usr/local/Cellar/lame/3.99.5/lib \
-L/usr/local/Cellar/libogg/1.3.2/lib \
-L/usr/local/Cellar/theora/1.1.1/lib \
-L/usr/local/Cellar/libvorbis/1.3.5/lib \
-L/usr/local/Cellar/xvid/1.3.4/lib" \
--extra-cflags="-I/usr/local/Cellar/lame/3.99.5/include \
-I/usr/local/Cellar/libogg/1.3.2/include \
-I/usr/local/Cellar/theora/1.1.1/include \
-I/usr/local/Cellar/libvorbis/1.3.5/include \
-I/usr/local/Cellar/xvid/1.3.4/include"
```

depending on your required libs and versions this may be different of course.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Macports (http://www.macports.org/) to install ffmped or libtheora?
If you don't have it ...download an install it.
then go into your console and execute this:

```
sudo port install libtheora
```

Comment: can I do the same with brew?

Comment: Nope, brew doesn't have a repo for libtheora.